# How to integrate $\sqrt{1+(2/3)x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, radicals

How would you solve the following (step by step please!):
$$\int^6_5\sqrt{1+\frac23x}\ dx$$

I started with $u=1+\frac23x$, $du=\frac23\,dx$, now what?

Comment: Now it is almost finished. We get $dx=\frac{3}{2}\,du$, so our integral is $\int_{u=13/3}^5 \frac{3}{2}u^{1/2}\,du$.

Comment: $\int\sqrt u\ du=\frac23u^{3/2}+C$

Comment: Where does the 1 go?

Comment: @Kudla69 What is the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}\left( 1+\frac{2}{3}x \right)$? That should answer the question of where the $1$ went.

Comment: It gets wrapped up in the translation to limits in terms of $u$ in place of $x$, or else you put it back in place of $u$ at the end and put in the original limits after integrating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$\int^6_5\sqrt{1+\frac23x}\ dx$$

Now let $u = 1 + \frac{2}{3}x$, and $du = \frac{2}{3}\ dx$, so that means $dx = \frac{3}{2}du$, so make the subsitution:

$$\int^{6 = x}_{5=x}\sqrt{u}\frac{3}{2}\ du = \frac{3}{2} \int^{6 = x}_{5 = x}u^{\frac{1}{2}}\ du$$

Now we need to find the bounds for $u$, and then we will use the power rule for antiderivatives:
Since $ u = 1 + \frac{2}{3}x$, when $x = 6$, $u =5$, and when $x = 5$, $u =\frac{13}{3}$, so those are our new bounds.  So the integral is: $$\frac{3}{2} \int^{5}_{\frac{13}{3}}u^{\frac{1}{2}} du = \frac{3}{2}(\frac{2}{3}(5^\frac{3}{2}) - \frac{2}{3}(\frac{13}{3})^\frac{3}{2}) = 5^\frac{3}{2} - (\frac{13}{3})^\frac{3}{2} = \sqrt{125} - \sqrt{(\frac{13}{3})^3}$$$$ = 5\sqrt{5} - \frac{13\sqrt{\frac{13}{3}}}{3}$$

Alternately, instead of finding the new bounds for $u$, you can just put the antiderivative back in terms of $x$ and solve from there.

Comment: This is a definite intergral - there should be no "+ C" at the end on your last line.

Comment: I guess that's my cue to finally get some sleep.  Thanks.